# Call phing task from cron

Tags: php, cron, phalcon, phing

I am stuck from quite a few days,

I need few good ways to call phing task from cron job.

The actual issue is after calling phing task from cron, the php engine cannot locate the build.xml file, which is located to the main directory of my project

build.xml path : abc/build.xml

phing path    : abc/vendor/bin/phing

my cron      : 1 * * * * xyz/local/www/abc/vendor/bin/phing test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible solutions.

First one, you can use `cd` in your cron:

```
my cron : 1 * * * * cd /xyz/local/www/abc/ && vendor/bin/phing test
```

---

Second solution, use the `-f` option:

```
my cron : 1 * * * * /xyz/local/www/abc/vendor/bin/phing -f /path/build.xml test
```

If you have problems with relative paths inside your buildfile you should also set the `basedir` attribute in the `<project>` tag:

```
<project default="help" name="my-project" basedir="/xyz/local/www/abc">
```

---

Sources:

https://superuser.com/questions/155576/linux-how-to-run-a-command-in-a-given-directory

https://www.phing.info/phing/guide/en/output/chunkhtml/ch02s03.html

https://www.phing.info/phing/guide/en/output/chunkhtml/ch03s05.html

Comment: the 1st solution worked for me, thanks a lot  

for me 2nd solution did work, couldnt identify the issue properly

and their is 1 more way but not recommended which is shell script